# How to get particular page URL in magento

Tags: magento

I would like to get a page's URL key in Magento.

For example, I have a CMS page called "What's New" with the identifier (or URL key) "whats_new". Its correct URL is therefore `http://mysite.com/whats_new`

Currently I use this code to echo its location:

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>whats_new
```

I feel it's bad practice because its identifier (or URL key) is administrable; if its URL key or identifier changes then the link will break. What is the proper way to echo its dynamic URL key? Perhaps something similar to Wordpress's `get_permalink('10')`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl( $pageId ) ?>
```

Replace `$pageId` with the correct id for the page you are linking to and it should work.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work too in the wysiwyg editor, to be able to link to a certain productpage? In one product I want to link to another product in the discription field, without copy/pasting the (current) SEO url. Better would be to make a link like <a href="get_permalink('10')">other product</a>. Is that possible? Because PHP is ofcourse not a option from within the WYSIWYG editor ...

Comment: @ButtleButkus: Thanks for intimating

Comment: @Josh What if i want url by store / language?

Comment: Just what i was looking for! Awesome! +1

Answer (score 19):

Try this

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('whats_new');?>
```

If you need to add url key dynamically then

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl($yourDynamicVariable);?>
```

of course you must implement the features that you need to fill the variable if url key is changed

Comment: +1 it's working but if i change the URL key whats_new to whats_new1 it will not work am i right . is there any good thing available in magento

Comment: I edited my answer, there's no magic and you still have to set your variables

Comment: If the value passed happens to be the name of a module then it gets rewritten to that module's front name. For example "adminhtml" becomes "admin". To avoid such potential rewrites try doing it like `getUrl('', array('_direct'=>$yourDynamicVariable))`. See [this wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters) for more details.

Comment: Which class is `$this` in this answer?

Comment: print_r(get_class($this)); but i guess some class inherited from template class

Comment: @AntonS S so this code probably won't work in controllers and models…

Comment: @feeela feel free to replace $this with any object you can ask this method from to use in models and controllers

Answer (score 9):

You shoud use `<?php echo Mage::getUrl('page-url.html); ?>`

Comment: Why this answer not upvoted? It will work in all cases (controller, model or view)

Comment: Surely you meant `.html`? Also, what happens if I change the page suffixes in config to `.php`?

Answer (score 5):

**In CMS Page**

```
{{store _direct="url_key"}}
```

**If you want in .phtml file then**

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl('url_key') ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Mage::getUrl(null, array('_direct' => $page->getIdentifier()));
```

Comment: That is the correct way..  it works also with an arbitrary identified, i.e.  `Mage::getUrl(null, array('_direct' =>  $url_key));`

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to retrieve the CMS page URL using the page identifier like,

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl('cms_page_identifier') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use

{{store direct_url="whats_new/"}}

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('whats_new');?>
```