# How to get page title by id in magento?

Tags: magento

I need to display a list of pages in the header (their title) and when the user clicks on a page title he will be directed to the corresponding page.

How can I obtain the title and the permalink of a page, knowing the page Id? For now i wrote `select page_id, title from cms_page here page_id in (6,7,8)`.

But isn't there a method in Magento that I can use to obtain this information?

Answer (score 1):

## How to add cms page in top link?

Goto page.xml(layout/page.xml) find topLinks then modify

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
```

to

```
 <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks">
   <action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>Your page </label><url>your-page</url><title>YOUR PAGE</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>80</position></action>

  </block>
```

## How to get particular page URL using page id ?

use this refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430538/how-to-get-particular-page-url-in-magento)

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl( 1 ) ?>
```

## Adding Dynamically cms pages to top link

This one can collect all cms pages

```
$cms = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
```

To get store id use bellow one.

```
$store_id = Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getCode();
$cms->addStoreFilter($store_id);
$cms->load();
```

Then you can extract it as you want.[Here More information](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/12462/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, that was useful but isn't a way to do it without writing xml code? for example my client will probably change the name of some pages in the admin part, but in the xml will be displayed the old names. Wouldn't that be a problem? My client is an operator, not a web developer, he only knows how to pres buttons, not to write code. That's why i need to obtain those informations (in php) by passing the page ids ...

Comment: @GrigorasCosmin:Added more taste with the answer.Hope this help you !

Answer (score 1):

To get the CMS page's title from its id:

```
$page_title = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($page_id)->getTitle();
```

To get the CMS page's url from its id:

```
$page_url = Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl($page_id);
```